# Using jq to compare two fields from same json and printing some other field as a result

Tags: json, jq

I have json data in following format

```
{
  "body": [
    {
      "username": "name1",
      "id": "4444"
    },
    {
      "username": "name2",
      "id": "5555"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "input": "name1"
  }}
```

Given this data I want to match the "username"s in the body with "meta.input" and if there is a match return/print related id.

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***jq*** solution:

```
jq '.meta.input as $meta | .body[] | select(.username == $meta).id' input.json
```

The output:

```
"4444"
```

---

- `.meta.input as $meta` - assigning `.meta.input` key value to `$meta` variable for further comparison

Comment: If you just want the actual text of id, the `-r` option will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

This should be as simple as that:

```js
var data = {
  "body": [{
    "username": "name1",
    "id": "4444"
  }, {
    "username": "name2",
    "id": "5555"
  }],
  "meta": {
    "input": "name1"
  }
};

function getID(data) {
  var username = data.meta.input;
  var userID;

  for (i in data.body) {
  
    if (data.body[i].username === username) {
      userID = data.body[i].id;
      break;
    }
  }

  return userID;
}

var id = getID(data);
alert(id);
```